# How to configure proxy servers with puppet nginx?

Tags: nginx, vagrant, unicorn, puppet

Currently I have a proxy setup with this config, that i'd like to setup using https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-nginx

```
upstream unicorn {
 server unix:/home/vagrant/website/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0; 
}

server {
 listen 80 default;
 root /home/vagrant/website/public; 
 try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
 location @unicorn {
   proxy_pass http://unicorn;
 }
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
}
```

So far I have:

```
node default {
 class { 'nginx': }
 nginx::resource::upstream { 'unicorn':
   ensure  => present,
   members => [
     'unix:/home/vagrant/website/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;'
   ],
 }
}
```

But I'm not sure how to add the details for the server section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nginx::resource::vhost`

The source of the repo you are using gives a breakdown of the commands you will need to use:

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-nginx/blob/master/manifests/resource/vhost.pp

Comment: You might be better to use this forked version: https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx

Use the `proxy` argument and set it to `unicorn`.
Use the `vhost_cfg_append` argument and give it your error page details.

Comment: Hmm.. link looks dead, Jim